# android - .apk file is not modified

Tags: android, android-install-apk

i run the application using eclipse at this .apk file is not modified. Suppose i used the .apk file in the device at the installation time  i got the “Parse Error : There is a problem parsing the package”. How to solve this? can anybody help me.

For this i deleted the .apk file from the bin folder and after run the app using eclipse. Generally in this case .apk file is generated. but here it is not generated. but .class file are generated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this errors in 2 cases-

1. When I changed the package name of the app (In that case, uninstall old and run it again)
2. When you install this APK from Gmail in < Android 2.2 phones.

Since you are getting this in Eclipse, did you change the package name or edited in Manifest?

Comment: i modified <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"  
          android:targetSdkVersion="8"/> in manifest. i set the properties in the eclipse to android2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Try: Project -> Clean.
Or, try: Right click on project -> Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.
In the same menu you can change the package project.

Comment: i did but still i apk is not generated when i run the app